# FlatList not scrolling in React-Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to build a news feed on React Native using `FlatList`. I want it to be similar to Tik Tok's feed, each item in the `FlatList` occupies the whole screen.

Right now it has the correct layout that I want, but the issue is the feed is not scrollable.

For some reason, the `FlatList` becomes not scrollable if I set the child to have `height: '100%'`. When I change it to `height: 1000`, it's scrollable, but I don't want to hard code the height.

I would be appreciated if you offer any help at all!

Here is the feed component:

```
const Feed = () => {

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <FeedItem
        id={item.id.toString()}
        videoUrl={item.videoUrl}
        index={index}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.children}
        data={someData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
      />
  );
}

// styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    height: '100%'
  },
  children: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  }
})
```

And here is each item in the feed:

```
import { Video } from 'expo-av';

const FeedItem = ({ id, videoUrl, index }) => {
  return (
    <Video
      source={{ uri: videoUrl }}
      style={styles.backgroundVideo}
    />
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundVideo: {
    height: '100%'     // FIXME: problematic
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you tried ```Dimensions.get('window').height;```?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. But that doesn't take the bottom nav into account. I want it to occupy the screen without overlapping with the navbar.

Comment: Hi, facing this exact issue. Did you, by any chance, find a way to resolve this?

Comment: Hey Chogo, I ended up using ViewPager from @react-native-community/viewpager. It's something like <ViewPager style={{flex:1}} />

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
const FeedItem = ({ id, videoUrl, index }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <Video
        source={{ uri: videoUrl }}
        style={styles.videoStyle}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  videoStyle: {
    height: Screen.height,     // Remove this
    width: Screen.width
  },
});
```

Comment: But if I do that, the video is not visible at all (zero height). How do I fix that?

Comment: I've tried using the screen dimension. The only thing I don't like is the video will overlap with the bottom navigation bar. That's why I tried height: 100% to make it fill the remaining screen.